biblatex with authoryear style not showing extradate
When compiling the main.tex file (see below), I am getting:

However, I am hoping to get Goodfellow, et al. (2014a) and Goodfellow, et al. (2014b). I have gone through the manual for biblatex and it seems that extradate is not working. Could someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Much much appreciated!
Here is the main.tex file:
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[american]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\usepackage[backend=biber,
            natbib=true,
            style=authoryear,
            maxcitenames=1,
            mincitenames=1,
            maxbibnames=99,
            hyperref=true]{biblatex} % for references

\addbibresource{reference.bib}

\begin{document}

\citet{goodfellow2014explaining} \\
\citet{goodfellow2014generative} \\

\citep{goodfellow2014explaining} \\
\citep{goodfellow2014generative}


\printbibliography

\end{document}

and here is the reference.bib file:
@string{iclr = "International Conference on Learning Representations (ICLR)"}
@string{neurips = "Advances in Neural Information Processing Systems (NeurIPS)"}

@inproceedings{goodfellow2014generative,
  title={Generative adversarial nets},
  author={Goodfellow, Ian and Pouget-Abadie, Jean and Mirza, Mehdi and Xu, Bing and Warde-Farley, David and Ozair, Sherjil and Courville, Aaron and Bengio, Yoshua},
  booktitle=neurips,
  year={2014}
}

@inproceedings{goodfellow2014explaining,
  title={Explaining and harnessing adversarial examples},
  author={Goodfellow, Ian and Shlens, Jonathon and Szegedy, Christian},
  booktitle=iclr,
  year={2014}
}


Try with uniquelist=false.

THANK YOU! YOU ARE AMAZING!
